# IBM Maximo Application Suite

Tags: ldap, maximo

I have a query regarding the IBM MAS and LDAP.

Question> If the MAS env is integrated with LDAP, does it mean we can use user coming from both AD and locally added in MAS?

Could you please attach a reference link for the same.

Thank you.

I found below link
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mas-cd/continuous-delivery?topic=identity-ldap-user-registry-synchronization

and below answer
when creating user, you select - authenticaiton mode: SAML, LDAP or Internal MAS user

I need more elaboration on the query.